# How to implement murmurhash3 in VBNET

Tags: vb.net, arrays, hash, bit-manipulation, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to implement murmurhash3 in vb.net and trying to convert from this [C# implementation](http://blog.kejser.org/murmurhash-in-c/)

first part of the function in c#

```
public static SqlInt32 MurmurHash3(SqlBinary data)
{
const UInt32 c1 = 0xcc9e2d51;
const UInt32 c2 = 0x1b873593;

int curLength = data.Length;    /* Current position in byte array */
int length = curLength;   /* the const length we need to fix tail */
UInt32 h1 = seed;
UInt32 k1 = 0;

/* body, eat stream a 32-bit int at a time */
Int32 currentIndex = 0;
while (curLength >= 4)
{
  /* Get four bytes from the input into an UInt32 */
  k1 = (UInt32)(data[currentIndex++]
    | data[currentIndex++] << 8
    | data[currentIndex++] << 16
    | data[currentIndex++] << 24);

  /* bitmagic hash */
  k1 *= c1;
  k1 = rotl32(k1, 15);
  k1 *= c2;

  h1 ^= k1;
  h1 = rotl32(h1, 13);
  h1 = h1 * 5 + 0xe6546b64;
  curLength -= 4;
}
```

And same in VB.net:

```
     Public Shared Function MurmurHash3(data As Byte()) As Int32
    Const c1 As UInt32 = &HCC9E2D51UI
    Const c2 As UInt32 = &H1B873593

    Dim curLength As Integer = data.Length
    ' Current position in byte array 
    Dim length As Integer = curLength
    ' the const length we need to fix tail 
    Dim h1 As UInt32 = seed
    Dim k1 As UInt32 = 0

    ' body, eat stream a 32-bit int at a time 
    Dim dBytes As Byte()
    Dim currentIndex As Int32 = 0
    While curLength >= 4
        ' Get four bytes from the input into an UInt32 
        dBytes = New Byte() {data(currentIndex), data(currentIndex + 1), data(currentIndex + 2), data(currentIndex + 3)}
        k1 = BitConverter.ToUInt32(dBytes, 0)

        currentIndex += 4
        ' bitmagic hash 

        k1 *= c1
        k1 = rotl32(k1, 15)
        k1 *= c2

        h1 = h1 Xor k1
        h1 = rotl32(h1, 13)
        h1 = h1 * 5 + &HE6546B64UI
        curLength -= 4
    End While
```

---

```
Private Shared Function rotl32(x As UInt32, r As Byte) As UInt32
    Return (x << r) Or (x >> (32 - r))
End Function
```

k1 *= c1
Throws error Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.

Any suggestions how this should be implemented? I'm Not sure how to do the Get four bytes from the input into an UInt32 part if that is the problem or is it related to something else since there are some differences in bitwise operations between C# and VB.

For the reference Java implementation also exists
https://github.com/yonik/java_util/blob/master/src/util/hash/MurmurHash3.java

Comment: Any reason you don't just use the C# code in a class library, calling it from your VB? Why risk getting a subtle error by porting?

Comment: Project + Properties, Compile tab, Advanced, tick the "Remove integer overflow checks" option.  Best done by keeping this code in a separate assembly.  Might as well be a C# one then of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'd first convert the 32-bit `k1` to a 64-bit variant first, e.g:

```
k1_64 = CType(k1, UInt64)
```

for modulo-32bit calculation, do

```
k1_64 = (k1_64 * c1) And &HFFFFFFFFUI
```

finally, recast back to 32-bit

```
k1 = CType(k1_64 And $HFFFFFFFFUI, UInt32)
```

to add more performance, you might want to consider replacing the `BitConverter.ToUInt` call with something else.

**EDIT :** Here's a simpler version without additional variable (but with a 'helper constant')

```
Const LOW_32 as UInt32 = &HFFFFFFFFUI
' ... intervening code ...
k1 = (1L * k1 * c1) And LOW_32
' ... later on ...
h1 = (h1 * 5L + &HE6546B64UL) And LOW_32
```

the `1L` forces the calculation within the parens to be performed as Long (Int64). The `And LOW_32` pares down the number of non-zero bits to 32, and the overall result is then automatically casted to UInt32. Similar thing happens on the `h1` line.

Reference: http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/08/secrets-and-lies-of-type-suffixes-in-c-and-vb-net/ (scroll down to the section "Secrets of constants and type suffixes")

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it possible to do the equivalent of unchecked {} in VB.NET? You could use a try/catch blocked and do the shift manually if you overflow. Just be careful, putting an error handler in there will slow down the hash calculation.